# Point Cloud - Principal Axes - Use of Inertia

Tags: components, pca, point-clouds, axes

I have got point clouds of different primitive objects (cone, plane, torus, cylinder, sphere, ellipsoid). The all vary in orientation, position and scaling. Furthermore all of them are initialized with a unique set of parameters (e.g. height, radius, etc.) so that their shape can be quiet different (some cones are tall, others are small and fat).

Now to my question:

I am trying to find the objects "principal components". Using PCA doesn't lead to good results, since rotated primitives can have their main variation in any direction (which doesn't have to be necessarily along the length of the objects).

The only chance that I see is to use somehow the symmetry of my primitives. Isn't there a method based on inertia? Maybe some way to find the main symmetry axis and two others perpendicular to it?

Can you give me some advice or point me to papers or implementations (maybe even python)?

Thanks a lot, Merlin.

PS: This is what I get if I only apply a PCA. Especially for cones this doesn't really work. Only cones that are almost identical in shape share the same orientation, but I need them all to point in one direction (e.g. up).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So you got cones and just need to rotate them all in the same direction?
If so you can fit a triangle to them and point the peak (e.g with the perpendicular bisectors of the sides) to your main axis.

Comment: I have got all the mentioned primitives (sphere, ellipsoid, ...). The reason the picture is only showing cones is that in this case PCA failed the most (all cones point more or less in different directions).

I just found this tutorial but I am not sure if it's going to be of any help. It seems that it calculates the principal components of point clouds by the inspection of inertia instead of PCA. 
http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/moment_of_inertia.php

What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

You have an interesting problem. Normally used shape descriptors ([VFH](https://willowgarage.com/sites/default/files/Rusu10IROS.pdf)) that are invariant to shape but not pose (which is what you would want, really) would not be invariant to stretching in the shape.

I think to succeed at this you need to be clearer about the invariants that you are trying to maintain when a shape changes. Is it a topological invariant? If so, then here is a good starting point: [https://www.google.com.tr/search?q=topologically+invariant+shape+descriptor](https://www.google.com.tr/search?q=topologically%20invariant%20shape%20descriptor)

Comment: The idea of the whole project is to feed my primitives (after some minor preprocessing) into a deep learner (stacked denoising autoencoder) to see if it's capable to learn meaningful features.  If that's the case it should be able to classify most of the primitives correctly.

So defining shape descriptors is exactly what I am trying to avoid. I don't want to apply any domain specific knowledge (feature engineering) before feeding my data to the machine learner. It should be as raw as possible. The only thing that I want to do upfront is to align all point clouds and to voxelize them.

Comment: I'm afraid that the alignment you intend to do is domain knowledge. It certainly is not immediately available from sensory data. Even if you use PCA you are making some assumptions about when two different configurations are the same shape (because you need those assumptions to motivate a choice of alignment - otherwise, how can you do alignment? You might have an answer I haven't thought of, but my view is that behind every alignment approach is such an assumption).

Comment: As such, I would expect the alignment to be learnt too if you really are using no assumptions - but then, deep learning, I am told, is magical.

Comment: Yes it's true. If I would try to find a perfect alignment I would have to make some assumptions. For primitives e.g. it would be, that all objects have a rotational symmetry. Therefore I will just stick to a pure PCA which at least orients similar objects in a similar fashion. This is totally generic and could be applied to any kind of input (maybe more complex CAD models, but also any n-dimensional data). If there is some remaining variation the machine learner will have to take care of it. That's what they are meant for ... interpreting inputs that haven't been learned in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to just stick to simple PCA since it's the only method that is totally generic and doesn't depend on prior (expert) knowledge about the data.